# Fabric.js - SVG export

Tags: fabricjs

Just another question about SVG export in Fabric.js, I have tried http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/ and I added two images to the canvas, then I applied shadow filter to them.

When I export it to image, looks nice, but when I export it to SVG, all images are not displayed. I used windows 7, Firefox 25, the filter is missing in SVG, it supposed to be located inside `<defs>`.

So my question is what I should know when I am doing with SVG from Fabric.js, if it didn't support somewhere, how could I add my own export method to its object, as I will use clip (not displayed in SVG too), shadow, and all other filters. Thanks.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="700" height="600" xml:space="preserve"><desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.4.0</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g transform="translate(237.81 209.86) rotate(36) scale(0.16 0.16)"><image xlink:href="http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug.jpg" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); opacity: 1;filter: url(#SVGID_5);" transform="translate(-360 -540)" width="720" height="1080" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image></g>
    <g transform="translate(479.6 187.6) rotate(3) scale(0.8 0.8)"><image xlink:href="http://fabricjs.com/assets/logo.png" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); opacity: 1;filter: url(#SVGID_4);" transform="translate(-137.5 -47.5)" width="275" height="95" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can overwrite toSVG method on an object itself or an its "class" (e.g. `fabric.Image.prototype.toSVG`) to add support for whatever is missing.